# I am flying from the UK to the EU. Can I bring meat products I bought previously in the EU?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, eu

I have some meat products I bought in an EU country. They are in factory shrink wrap, with the producing country prominently displayed. Then I went on to visit the UK. Now I am heading back to the EU, a different country. Is it allowed to bring these meat products back?

Answer (score 3):

The United Kingdom is not listed as country where exceptions are allowed in [REGULATION (EU) 2019/2122](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32019R2122#d1e32-53-1) Article 7(e)

- Andorra, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway, San Marino or Switzerland

There is no meation of returning goods, of EU origin, in their original undamaged, packaging.

Since meat products are listed in Part 2 of Annex I (List of goods which are not exempted from official controls at border control posts provided for in Article 7(c)), you should present/declare those goods to the customs official at the port of entry and let them decide if you may retain them or not.

Not declaring such items could lead to fines.